# White line underneath my transparent nav bar Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason there is a line underneath my Nav bar that stays there. It is fixed so when it scrolls down it stays. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I'm not really sure why. Here is my Nav HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container"> 
     <div class="navbar-header">  
     <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> 
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
       <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/themes/vip/techcrunch-2013/assets/images/logo.svg"/> 
     </a>

     </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
         <li><a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> Discover </a></li>
      </ul>


     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href="#"> Login </a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Sign up </a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS code for the nav:

```
.navbar  {
background:none;

}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
  color:white;

}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;

}
.navbar-brand img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a working snippet or ... some kind of demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `border: 1px solid transparent;` to your `navbar` rule.

You also have an extra `a` tag (`<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">`).

Working Example (with added mobile toggle fucntion).

```css
html,
body {
  background: darkblue;
}
/*THE ABOVE BACKGROUND RULE IS FOR DEMO ONLY*/

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .nav > li > a {
  color: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
        <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/themes/vip/techcrunch-2013/assets/images/logo.svg" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="index.html"> Home </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Discover </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"> Login </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Sign up </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can add this to remove the border from the collapse if you're using the mobile toggle:

```
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Working Example:

```css
html,
body {
  background: red;
}
/*THE ABOVE BACKGROUND RULE IS FOR DEMO ONLY*/

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .nav > li > a {
  color: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
        <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/themes/vip/techcrunch-2013/assets/images/logo.svg" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="index.html"> Home </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Discover </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"> Login </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Sign up </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this sorted it out!

Answer (score 0):

That's the white border from Bootstrap's `.navbar-default`. Just remove that class or put `border: none` inside your `.navbar` styles.